# CUDA Double pointer memory copy

Tags: cuda

I wrote my sample code like this.

```
int ** d_ptr;
cudaMalloc( (void**)&d_ptr, sizeof(int*)*N );

int* tmp_ptr[N];
for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    cudaMalloc( (void**)&tmp_ptr[i], sizeof(int)*SIZE );
cudaMemcpy(d_ptr, tmp_ptr, sizeof(tmp_ptr), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

And this code works well but after kernel launching I can't receive the result.

```
int* Mtx_on_GPU[N];
cudaMemcpy(Mtx_on_GPU, d_ptr, sizeof(int)*N*SIZE, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

At this point, segment-fault-error occurs. But I don't know what I'm wrong.

```
int* Mtx_on_GPU[N];
for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    cudaMemcpy(Mtx_on_GPU[i], d_ptr[i], sizeof(int)*SIZE, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

This code have also same error.

I think certainly my code has some mistakes but I can't find it during all daytime.

Give me some advice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the last line

```
cudaMemcpy(Mtx_on_GPU[i], d_ptr[i], sizeof(int)*SIZE, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

you are trying to copy data from the device to the host (NOTE: I assume that you allocated host memory for the `Mtx_on_GPU` pointers!)

However, the *pointers* are stored in device memory, so you can't access the directly from host side. The line should be

```
cudaMemcpy(Mtx_on_GPU[i], temp_ptr[i], sizeof(int)*SIZE, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

---

This may become clearer when using "overly elaborate" variable names:

```
int ** devicePointersStoredInDeviceMemory;
cudaMalloc( (void**)&devicePointersStoredInDeviceMemory, sizeof(int*)*N);

int* devicePointersStoredInHostMemory[N];
for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    cudaMalloc( (void**)&devicePointersStoredInHostMemory[i], sizeof(int)*SIZE );

cudaMemcpy(
    devicePointersStoredInDeviceMemory, 
    devicePointersStoredInHostMemory,
    sizeof(int*)*N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

// Invoke kernel here, passing "devicePointersStoredInDeviceMemory"
// as an argument
...

int* hostPointersStoredInHostMemory[N];
for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    int* hostPointer = hostPointersStoredInHostMemory[i]; 
    // (allocate memory for hostPointer here!)

    int* devicePointer = devicePointersStoredInHostMemory[i];

    cudaMemcpy(hostPointer, devicePointer, sizeof(int)*SIZE, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
}
```

---

EDIT in response to the comment:

The `d_ptr` is "an array of pointers". But the memory of this array is allocated with `cudaMalloc`. That means that it is located on the device. In contrast to that, with `int* Mtx_on_GPU[N];` you are "allocating" N pointers in **host** memory. Instead of specifying the array size, you could also have used `malloc`. It may become clearer when you compare the following allocations:

```
int** pointersStoredInDeviceMemory;
cudaMalloc((void**)&pointersStoredInDeviceMemory, sizeof(int*)*N);

int** pointersStoredInHostMemory;
pointersStoredInHostMemory = (void**)malloc(N * sizeof(int*));

// This is not possible, because the array was allocated with cudaMalloc:
int *pointerA = pointersStoredInDeviceMemory[0];

// This is possible because the array was allocated with malloc:    
int *pointerB = pointersStoredInHostMemory[0];
```

It may be a little bit brain-twisting to keep track of

- the type of the memory where the pointers are **stored**
- the type of the memory that the pointers are **pointing to**

but fortunately, it hardly becomes more than 2 indirections.

Comment: Oh my god. It works well clearly. Thanks!! But I have some adoubt. Both d_ptr and tmp_ptr use cudaMalloc but why I can access tmp_ptr although can't access d_ptr?

Comment: @Umbrella I added an EDIT, maybe it becomes clearer now

Comment: Really well outlined.   Bravo on this