# Address of double pointer cast to void**

Tags: c++, pointers, cuda

I was searching how to create an array of pointers and copy it to CUDA memory. I found this post [CUDA Double pointer memory copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23609770/cuda-double-pointer-memory-copy) but the following line in the accepted answer

```
int ** devicePointersStoredInDeviceMemory;
cudaMalloc( (void**)&devicePointersStoredInDeviceMemory, sizeof(int*)*N);
```

is bugging me a bit.
What's the meaning of passing the address of a double pointer and cast it to a `void**`?
Wouldn't `&devicePointerStoredInDeviceMemory` be the same as `int***` so why cast it to `void**` instead of `void***`?

It works, but I do not understand why.

Comment: Note: this is undefined behaviour in Standard C++, but the Windows API relies on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the meaning of passing the address of a double pointer and cast it to a void**? Wouldn't &devicePointerStoredInDeviceMemory be the same as int*** so why cast it to void** instead of void***?

The `cudaMalloc` function takes a `void **` as its first parameter, so if we're going to call `cudaMalloc`, that's the type we need. The purpose of the first parameter is to tell `codaMalloc` where to store the pointer to the memory we allocated.

You could do this just as well:

```
void *j;
cudaMalloc(&j, sizeof(int*)*N); // stores result in j
int **devicePointersStoredInDeviceMemory = (int **) j;
```

Comment: Oh I see now. So the `(void**)` could be interpreted as "give me the address of the variable you want me to allocate"? No matter if it is `int*` or `float**` or `double*****` if this is the idea I think I got it thanks

Comment: I would phrase it as "tell me where to store the address of the memory that I allocated for you". In this case, we want that memory to hold pointers to integers, so a pointer to the memory that will hold pointers to integers is of type `int **`.